# ASP.Net how to render all Trace section in contor

Tags: asp.net, trace

The default Trace section renders outside the  tag and breaks the page design

Please recomnd the way to display the Trace a the bottom of page and may be use come scrolling or collapsing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is true, ASP.NET in page trace puts the html outside of the `<html/>` tag

The System.Diagnostics trace is extensible and configurable... but the ASP.NET in page trace, as far as I can tell (from looking at the decompiled code with Reflector) is not extensible.

Option #1- Use Glipse @ http://getglimpse.com/  There appears to be a tab for trace. Last time I tried, the tool was optimized for MVC, but it's been rapidly expanding recently.

Option #2- Use a custom trace listener that writes to session or the Request.Items collection & on prerender, dump any trace values to a Label anywhere you'd like it. (A caveat to this technique is that anything that happens on page after pre-render will not be trace to the page-- onunload, end of request events would be invisible)

See here for many examples and a TraceListener base class that takes care of much of the boiler plate work of writing a custom TraceListener:

http://essentialdiagnostics.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Listeners&referringTitle=Home

Or log to a different trace listener altogether, like a file, the visual studio debug window, a database, etc.